# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: 14.04, python3, pip, pkg-config

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu for python 3.
when I run pip3:

```
sudo -H apt-get pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last:)
 File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Comment: You have typo in `apt-get pip3 install tensorflow-gpu` - it should be `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu`. Try to follow [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux).

Answer (score 5):

pkg_resources is a dependency of setuptools. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also related to pip installation module. You can also use python upgrade scripts.
Related issue on GitHub : [import error](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1167)
Issue ‘s about wrong importation from python 2.x modules versions which overlap with python3 dependencies. So the goal’s to upgrade pip. The best solution’s to install an upgraded OS for instance Bionic distribution and Do:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you summarize the content of the link you refer to, so that your answer reamins valid even if the linked page disappears?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using `python3` instead of `python`. And I found these instructions the codakid.com website.

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame==1.9.6 --user
```